# Please help in calculating Integral on the unit ball.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics, approximate-integration

For an arbitrary vector R with length $$R= |\overrightarrow{R}| > 1$$, we define the integral I(R), which is taken over a ball of unit radius:
$$I(R)=\int_{|r|\leq 1} \frac{dxdydz}{|R-r|^{2}}$$
where r=(x,y,z).
Your task in this exercise is to calculate the integral I(R) exactly, and see how accurate the approximation $$I(R)\simeq  \frac{4*pi}{3*R^{2}}$$ works for
$$(R\sim 1)$$

Find I(R) and enter the ratio in the answer
$$ \frac{I(R)}{\frac{4*pi}{3*R^{2}}} $$
at R=2

I tried solving it by using spherical coordinates and this is what i got

[image]

Comment: Hello welcome to Stack Exchange. We appreciate you showing your effort, however screen grabs of the bulk of your work are frowned upon as users who use screen readers cannot see them. You should use MathJax to type your equations.

Comment: As the above comment notes, well done showing your work, but you should really consider explicitly writing out your work using MathJax, rather than using images (which may be hard to read). People are unlikely to fully answer your question in its current state. Writing things out is site policy, and some users may straight up refuse to read your question if you don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Wlog we can assume that the vector $\overrightarrow{R}$ is
$$
(0,0,R)\,.
$$
The integral to calculate is
\begin{align}
I(\overrightarrow{R})&=\int_{\|\mathbf{x}\|\le 1}\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}{|\overrightarrow{R}-\mathbf{x}|^2}=\int_{\|\mathbf{x}\|\le 1}\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}
{x^2+y^2+(R-z)^2}\tag{1}\\
&=\int_0^1\int_{x^2+y^2\le 1-z^2}
\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}
{x^2+y^2+(R-z)^2}\,.
\end{align}
For fixed $z\,,$ the $dx\,dy$-integral becomes in two dimensional polar coordinates
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r\,d\varphi\,dr}{r^2+(R-z)^2}
=2\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\frac{r\,dr}{r^2+(R-z)^2}\\[2mm]
&=\pi\int_{(R-z)^2}^{1-z^2+(R-z)^2}\frac{du}{u}=\pi\log\frac{1-z^2+(R-z)^2}{(R-z)^2}\,.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Therefore,

\begin{align}
I(\overrightarrow{R})&=\pi\int_0^1\log\Big(1-z^2+(R-z)^2\Big)\,dz-\pi\int_0^1\log\Big((R-z)^2\Big)\,dz\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
From
\begin{align}
1-z^2+(R-z)^2=1+R^2-2Rz
\end{align}
we get the first integral in (3) as
$$
\frac{1}{2R}\int_{(R-1)^2}^{R^2+1}\log u\,du=\Bigg[\frac{u\log u-u}{2R}\Bigg]_{(R-1)^2}^{R^2+1}=\frac{(R^2+1)\log(R^2+1)-(R-1)^2\log((R-1))^2+2R}{2R}\,.
$$
The second integral in (3) we get as
$$
\int_{R-1}^R\log(u^2)\,du=\Bigg[u\log(u^2)-2u\Bigg]_{R-1}^R=R\log(R^2)-(R-1)\log((R-1)^2)-2\,.
$$

Someone thinks that $I(R)\approx \frac{4\pi}{3R^3}$ at least when $R$ is large.
However I believe that it should be
$$\boxed{\quad
I(R)\approx \frac{4\pi}{3R^\color{red}{2}}\,.\quad}
$$
Proof. Pulling out $R^2$ from the denominator of  (1) we get for large $R$
$$
I(\overrightarrow{R})=\frac{1}{R^2}
\int_{\|\mathbf{x}\|\le 1}\frac{dx\,dy\,dz}
{\frac{x^2+y^2}{R^2}+(1-z/R)^2}
\approx\frac{1}{R^2}\int_{\|\mathbf{x}\|\le 1}\,dx\,dy\,dz
=\frac{4\pi}{3R^2}\,.
$$

Here is a log-log graph:

[image]

Comment: A log-log plot may be more helpful for demonstrating that $I(R)\sim 4\pi/(3R^3)$ for large $R$.

Comment: @Semiclassical are we sure it is $I(R)\sim 4\pi/(3R^3)$ and not $I(R)\sim 4\pi/(3R^\color{red}{2})\,?$

Comment: You're correct, I made a typo versus the OP. (But it looks like you have it as cubic in your post as well.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I just took that from that other heated discussion without thinking. Thanks for bringing this up will update the post.

Comment: @KurtG. what would you say the value of your integral is at R=2?

Comment: @vanshsaxena  You could take the formulas and calculate but I will do that for you: $I(2)\approx 0.751496\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. i could and i did do that, i just wanted to make sure that the answer is wrong.

Comment: @KurtG. i did the integral my way as well the answer is still coming out to be wrong. I think there is some approximation required

Comment: according to me the answer should look something like $$\frac{4*pi}{3*R^{2}}[1+ (...)]$$

Comment: @vanshsaxena "Something like ..." . I showed that my $I(R)$ is asymptotically equal to $4\pi/(3R^2)\,.$ It is therefore *trivial* that *my* $I(R)$ is *also* "something like" $4\pi/(3R^2)\dot (1+...)\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. yes the integral you took is correct but the expression in the (1+...) dots will give the correct answer. I am just guessing over here as well

Comment: @vanshsaxena Aha. The integral I took is correct? Thank you. To get the expression in the dots do you not just have to back it out from the formulas I derived?

Comment: @KurtG. Yes the integral is correct but the answer still remains a mystery to the world

Comment: @vanshsaxena . Feel free to elaborate in detail by editing your question. The steps I took are calculus one level and if there is a mistake one should be able to spot it. There is no mystery in this at all.

Comment: @KurtG. This was the last detail given in the question.

Comment: @vanshsaxena You mean that handwritten image? The commenters on Jan 15 already urged you to type this in MathJax. Before this has not happened I won't waste any more time on this.

Comment: As an extension of the proof of $I(r)\sim 4\pi/(3R^2)$, one can use the generating function for [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html) to expand the initial integrand. This yields $I(R)$ as an infinite series of elementary integrals. (One could presumably resum this but it seems rather annoying.)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is an approximation, not the correct solution since you are not taking a limit. The trick is to do the integral in spherical coordinates, but *centered at the point $(0,0,R)$*. In other words

$$\begin{cases}x = r\sin\theta\cos\varphi \\ y = r\sin\theta\sin\varphi \\ z = R + r\cos\theta\end{cases}$$

which orients the sphere in the $z$ direction, giving the equation

$$x^2+y^2+(z-R)^2 = 1$$

Can you take it from here?

($\textbf{HINT}$: convert the above equation into spherical coordinates and solve for $\theta$, $\textbf{not}$ $r$. Then integrate with respect to $\theta$ first.)